# efficient (low bandwidth) browser-friendly way to show alternating texts on webpage with fadein/fadeout

Tags: javascript, html, fadein, fadeout

I'm looking for a light-weight, low bandwidth, cross-browser solution to show some alternating texts in a div on webpage with fadein/fadeout.

So no including of entire Jquery JavaScript libraries.

The texts may simply be hard-coded in html.

Comment: Do you want to rotate the text too?

Comment: Not necessary. Text don't move, they just fade in and then after sometime it fades out and the next text fades in, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of tutorials to produce simple fadein/out functionality in javascript without jQuery, here is one I found thanks to google.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-simple-fade-animation

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is by using transparent text color. You just increase the color transparency from 0 to 1 for fade in and then back down for the fade out. This is done in non IE browsers with RGBA like that:

```
div#someDiv
{
color: rgba(198,222,162,.60);
}
```

Set the div style with JS

For IE, use:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#66C6DEA2,endColorstr=#66C6DEA2)";
```

Here you must increase and decrease this HEX value #66